# Counting chain maps

Tags: homological-algebra, homology, vector-spaces

I initially asked this question over at math stack exchange, you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347508/counting-chain-maps). I haven't really gotten any traction and I'm beginning to wonder if maybe its a harder question than I originally thought. Anyway, I thought I would try my luck here.

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and let $C_{\cdot}$ and $K_{\cdot}$ be bounded chain complexes with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$. Then the set of chain maps $f_{\cdot}:C_{\cdot}\to K_{\cdot}$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space which we denote by $W=\mathrm{Hom}_{Ch_{\mathbb{K}}}(C_{\cdot},K_{\cdot})$. In fact, if $V_{k}=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(C_{k},K_{k})$ is the space of linear maps from $C_{k}$ to $K_{k}$, then I guess $W$ should be a proper subspace of $\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{N}}V_{k}$ and hence is finite dimensional.

**Question:** What is the dimension of $W$?

My feeling is that one can determine the dimension in homological terms, but computing a basis is probably difficult.

Comment: Your feeling is correct. By writing $C_*=B_*\oplus H_*\oplus B_{*-1}$ (and similar for $K$) and spelling out what it means to commute with $d$, you can easily find the dimension.